# Comment vaccuming removing comments pointing out bad code?

Tags: discussion

So I completely understand removing comments on discussions such as "why am I getting downvotes" and issues with the code that are fixed through edits.

What I don't understand is removing comments that point out additional bugs in the code.

I only caught this because whenever I get an upvote I got back to the question to check out if there are still any active conversations. I'd rather not post the question itself to avoid a witch hunt or a meta effect, but the offending question asked about a single bug in a C++ loop related to undefined behavior.

OP's code also contained a myriad of additional bugs along side the thing that was causing the issue OP was worried about, (memory-leaks, deleting things that should not have been deleted, and an overall methodology which was just plain wrong C++). There were pointed out in the comments on the question: the appropriate place, as the comments did not answer OP's question. OP never edited these bugs out the question.

A vacuumer came along and removed ALL the comments to the question...I can see a beginner looking for answers seeing that code and being led down the wrong path because the flags of "This code is bad for more reasons than OP thought" had all been removed. What is the correct thing to do in this case? My options are, as I see it:

- Downvote and move on and hope other people do the same
- Edit OP's post
- Add the additional bugs to my answer

Comment: Beginners often post code in questions that is riddled with bugs. Just because their *code* is bad, however, doesn't mean the *question* is bad, so I wouldn't downvote a question just for that reason. Remember, comments are ephemeral; anything you want to be permanent should be included in an answer. A good answer would point out the particular issue causing the bug; a *great* answer would also point out all of the other issues with the code.

Comment: Are you referring to the comments on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389220/freeing-memory-allocated-to-the-heap-stored-inside-a-vector ? There was a heated argument there, which got flagged, so a moderator decided it was easier to clean the whole thing out to focus on the answers. I've undeleted a select few comments before the insults started, but comments are ephemeral things and you shouldn't be surprised if ones involved in an argument are removed.

Comment: @BradLarson ha busted yeah that was the one. I agree that those are the only comments that should be brought back to life. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think *vacuuming* is the right word. Maybe *garbage collecting* would be better.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I agree that bad code != bad question. The "bad question", in this case, part comes from asking about many things at the same time, which provides an unsearchable question.

Comment: More evidence that treating comments as ephemeral is a **fundamentally flawed philosophy**.

Comment: I'm the one who wiped them. I'm actually slightly surprised I didn't undelete a few of those; the ones @BradLarson did, specifically. My bad!

Comment: I'm really sick and tired of this "comments are ephemeral" nonsense.  Comments are a Good Thing.  Comment-thread discussions often add materially to an answer in a way that would be difficult to fold back into the answer -- for instance, they often go into the problem space *around* the answer.  The system needs to be improved so that comment threads are first-class citizens of the platform, not unloved stepchildren.

Comment: (For instance, moderators should have ways of intervening in an argument that are less prone to collateral damage than deleting all the comments is.)

Comment: @Zack - Could we have "Protected Comments" that get attached to the answer but are separate, do you think?

Comment: @misterManSam: Who decides which comments should be "protected"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - \*shrug\* - well, if it's my answer, maybe I could "promote" some key comments that may not necessarily be needed in the answer itself. I can put anything into my answer, so why can't I choose the comments I deem relevant to it and sticky them. \*shrug\*

Comment: @misterManSam I don't know if that is valid. In this particular example, the "insults" started flying because OP didn't like the fact that people were criticizing the rest of the code. If the poster is unknowlegable, biased, or simply upset they could use the "sticky" tag to shape the organic discussion of a topic in ways that reflect their view and not that of the group. And when we are passionate about a topic, we are more likely to sticky unrelevant/inappropriate comments (like those insulting members of the opposing group) that *should* be removed.

Comment: @misterManSam: You're supposed to take the information in the comments and merge them into the answer with your narrative skills, resulting in a polished final product rather than some "timeline of opinion".

Answer (score 3):

> What is the correct thing to do in this case?

Making a meta post was a good start.

> Downvote and move on and hope other people do the same

One might argue that bad code doesn't necessitate a downvote, but if the code is so bad that you're spending more time fixing the bugs than answering the question, it is probably not a very useful question. The burden should be placed on the question asker, not the answerer, to fix all of the bugs.

> Edit OP's post

Once you start down this road, you'll probably end up rewriting the entire program. It's better to post corrections as comments or more reliably as an answer, since comments are considered second-class citizens.

> Add the additional bugs to my answer

You don't have any obligation to fix the outstanding bugs in the answer, so long as you address the main problem. Many people will address the most obvious problems like addressing manual memory management, or trivial things that take no time to point out. You can opt to individually pick out each bug like you did, but I find that it's a waste of effort. You gain nothing, and the OP gains nothing because you debugged their program for them.

Comment: I've seen ".. so long as you address the main problem.." answers followed up by the OP with "thx for ur help but it dosent work" (paraphrasing from memory), followed by *extensive* hand-helding comments. Is there *at that time* a valid close vote reason? "Visibly lacking basic knowledge to understand the problem", maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I think the biggest problem here is that comments are not a particularly good medium for communication other than requesting clarification. Something like pointing out problems in the code not directly related to the question should either simply be part of your answer or added as a community wiki. I'll often do the latter when good answers have already been posted, as a community wiki doesn't detract from those existing good answers and only serves to offer more good, information for the OP and any other users who stumble upon the question.

Comment: The problem with posting all those side-issues and general advice as an answer is simple: It is not an answer. As Lightness commented above, they should be used to correct the post and then swiftly removed.